# How to show time in a YouTube description without YouTube hyperlinking the time to a certain point in the video?

Tags: youtube

I have a YouTube video description that contains text describing a date and time of a meeting in the format of $date HH:MM - HH:MM.

However, YouTube is interpreting those as MM:SS MM:SS times and hyperlinking them to those times within the video itself.

I tried preceding the times with a backslash (i.e. \12:34) to escape the time so YouTube wouldn't interpret it as such but it did not work. See screenshots below. Advice?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube is interpreting the time format

```
HH:MM
```

as timestamps to the video content. Every valid time is accepted as timestamp, even outside of the video play time. Therefore, to show time in a YouTube description without YouTube hyperlinking, a different format has to be used to represent time.

Some examples:

```
13 : 14 - 15 : 40
13h14 - 15h40
```